# Directory.GetFiles returns weird, non existant but existant files

Tags: c#, getfiles

I am currently working on a user-folder backup solution.

At first I noticed the issue because I hat weird Documents in my backup such as:

```
ZZZZZ2292124227.doc
```

Upon further inspection, i found that `Directory.GetFiles()` returns these files.
Files seem to be all kinds of types, all very small, do not contain valid, readable data and are not visible in the windows file explorer or in powershell.
For example (powershell dir):

```
PS C:\Users\user> dir -Force


    Verzeichnis: C:\Users\user


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                3D Objects
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Anwendungsdaten
d--h--        13.01.2022     10:00                AppData
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Contacts
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Cookies
d-r---        09.02.2022     12:52                Desktop
d-r---        01.02.2022     08:33                Documents
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Downloads
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Druckumgebung
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Eigene Dateien
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Favorites
d--hs-        09.02.2022     12:52                IntelGraphicsProfiles
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Links
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Lokale Einstellungen
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Music
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Netzwerkumgebung
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:01                OneDrive
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Pictures
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Recent
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Saved Games
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Searches
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                SendTo
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Startmenü
d-r---        13.01.2022     10:00                Videos
d--hsl        13.01.2022     10:00                Vorlagen
-a-h--        06.07.2022     11:06        1572864 NTUSER.DAT
-a-hs-        13.01.2022     10:00              0 ntuser.dat.LOG1
-a-hs-        13.01.2022     10:00         262144 ntuser.dat.LOG2
-a-hs-        13.01.2022     10:25          65536 NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TM.blf
-a-hs-        13.01.2022     10:00         524288 NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
-a-hs-        13.01.2022     10:00         524288 NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
---hs-        13.01.2022     10:00             20 ntuser.ini


PS C:\Users\user>
```

However, `FileInfo[] files = currentDirectory.GetFiles();` will return a lot more such as:

```
C:\Users\user\XORXOR1982804314.txt
C:\Users\user\XORXOR3753157645.png
C:\Users\user\!!!!!2857851130.jpg
C:\Users\user\fVAYIy1051591475.docx
```

eventhough, neither explorer nor powershell show these files, I can put their path into explorer and it will attempt to open it (although unsuccessfully, the data is garbage). For the png file, for example, windows photo view fails to open the file but can show the file details:
[image]

[image]
The files are all relatively recent (max 2 months old), they have been exactly one time written to and are at most a few kb large. Has anyone an idea what these files are?

UPDATE:
Rather than coming from a malware these files (and folders) come from our corporate antivirus called `Traps`/ `Cortex XDR`

These Files appear to be "virtual files". They do not exist on the disk but get displayed to the software in order to prevent ransomeware attacks. Furthermore, my user profile copy/backup will replicate these non existent files in the output directory, effectively junking up the backup.

some more information can be found in the Cortex community forums:
https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/t5/endpoint-traps-discussions/zzzzz-and-thousands-of-that-kind-of-files-on-hdd/td-p/191025

so how to circumvent that stuff? for now, I have applied a text filter but the namings of these files might change in the future.

Comment: I think you are listing the files from the wrong directory when using `GetFiles()`, but since you have blurred the paths (I don't know why since it's not sensitive data) it's hard to confirm that.

Comment: I guess your windows explorer is set to only show files that do not have the attributes "hidden". If you get weird files you can always try to open them with a text editor and look for the header, maybe you get a clue there. As for Directory.GetFiles: you can include or exlude file attributes 
files.Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden));

Comment: Do happen to have had problems with malware lately?

Comment: These look like the kind of files that an antimalware application might use, by periodically checking if the contents of the files (which all have extensions that promise juicy targets in the form of office documents and mails) have been compromised (encrypted) by ransomware.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌ ǝɔıʌ usernames are sensitive data in a corporate environment. Hence the username is blurred.

Comment: @MarcWittmann not all these files are hidden. Even if they are not, they are not shown in explorer. Even if hidden files are shown in the explorer, these files do not appear

Comment: "Circumvent[ing] that stuff" should not be possible from your code alone -- if it was, ransomware could circumvent it too. Likely the software uses either a file system filter or direct DLL injection to achieve its goals. Explorer not showing it might be a result of the software explicitly whitelisting it as a "safe" application that should not be lied to (or perhaps even more primitive as "trusted" because it's in the Windows system directory). You'd have to ask the antimalware vendor how this mechanism works and how your application might be exempted from it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for the information I found more information on our antivirus provider. I have been able to circumvent them somewhat as the filenames always start the same (great "anti-malware"!) however, im still looking for a proper solution